# global comment option for R markdown in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

To change the leading characters for the output a knitr chunk in .Rmd has a comment option, like

````
```{r comment = ""}
1:100
```
````

Is there a way to set this globally, not separately for every chunk?

```
opts_knit$set(comment = "")
```

does not work and I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `opts_chunk$set()` because that is a *chunk* option; `opts_knit` is for package options (sorry about the similar names which apparently confused you). See http://yihui.name/knitr/options