# knitr executing R code chunks in HTML-style comments

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Using **Rstudio** to edit an **Rmarkdown** file, I use HTML comments mark out large blocks that I don't want to have processed or in the output. This works just fine in Rstudio, which ignores everything in the comments. However, when I ask Rstudio to knit the document, **knitr** is executing the **R** code blocks in the comments.

Here's an MWE .Rmd file:

````
# Important stuff I want to see
This is what I want to see:
```{r}
pi # I like pi
```
<!---
**This section commented out, as not ready to be knit yet**
This is what I do not want to see:
```{r}
cake # I also like cake, but it's undefined
```
-->
````

This causes knitr to fail with `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'cake' not found ... Execution halted`

Is there an easy way to comment out whole swathes of an Rmarkdown file which prevents knitr from executing the R code chunks in the comments?

I have looked at [global comment option for R markdown in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11190281/5568465) and [Comments in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4823468/5568465), as well as https://yihui.name/knitr/, but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Just selecting the whole part and do Ctrl + Shift + C ?

Comment: Just FYI https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1363

Comment: Thanks Yihui -- I will remember to look there next time I have an issue. Thanks also for a fantastic tool!

Answer (score 1):

Taking jburkhardt's idea of using `eval=F`, this works as a way of doing block comments where knitr does not execute the R code blocks:

````
Stuff I want to see...
```{r}
pi
```

<!--
This is added at the beginning of the comment:
```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval= FALSE)
```

Stuff I have commented out:

```{r}
cake
```

This is added to the end of the comment:
```{r, include=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval= TRUE)
```
-->

More stuff I want to see:
```{r}
2*pi
```
````

It's a bit clunky, and it's certainly not bulletproof (for example, knitr will still run any code blocks it finds with explicit `eval=true`), but it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Select lines before and after the `{r}` code chunk and use Control/Shift-C (pc) to comment out.  You will get this kind of syntax; it won't knit, and won't give an error.

````
<!-- **This section commented out, as not ready to be knit yet** -->
<!-- This is what I do not want to see: -->
<!-- ```{r} -->
<!-- cake # I also like cake, but it's undefined -->
<!-- ``` -->
````

Comment: Well, that works :) It's kind of the nuclear option, though. I guess I am really looking for a block comment rather than a line-wise comment. This is kind of unwieldy for large sections (which I have), and means you have to uncomment line-wise when you copy/paste chunks between the commented section and elsewhere in the document.
Any thoughts on a block comment that works with `knitr`?

Comment: It's marginally better for my purposes to use the html block comment as I had it, and then just add another comment character to the beginning of every line inside that, like a `#`. This is less visual noise since it's only a single character in the left margin, and easier to tidy up when copy-pasting later. But it's still line-wise... (I actually do my editing in vim, but interact with knitr through Rstudio...)

Answer (score 0):

In the second code junk you could set `eval=F` until you have finished this part of your code.

````
<!--
**This section commented out, as not ready to be knit yet**
This is what I do not want to see:
```{r eval=F}
cake # I also like cake, but it's undefined
```
-->
````

Comment: Actually, I like your idea here. It does not scale directly to large sections with multiple code blocks, but setting the default chunk options to be `eval=FALSE` at the head of the comment, and back to `eval=TRUE` at the tail, which just do what I need